# compare catalog and compressed catalog (is there new changes)

Tags: linux, compression, diff, ramdisk, tmpfs

I want to compare catalog with compressed without extracting or compress files and compare. Is there any way to compare directory with compressed directory ?

Example:
I have some files in tmpfs (ramdisk), before server shutdown, I need to save files to disk. In my opinion best way is compress files and save to disk like a file. On start server (system) I want to decompress files in to the ramdisk. But after couple days ramdisk files will be updated (different with compress file backup).

How to compare and merge diff ?

Regards,
Nerus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing:

```
tar -tvf foo.tar.gz
```

will show the contents of the compressed file without decompressing. You can then compare the files.

Comment: I'll use 'tar -df ramdisk.tar.bz2 -C /'. how to replace different files from directory in compressed file, how to create automated merge ?

Comment: @Nerus With the -u parameter of tar, it should update only the new files in the compressed files. I have not tried it before, so I cannot give you more advice.